# Webserver in docker container is not reachable via the internet

Tags: docker

I've been reading: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#user-defined-networks

I've created my own network (`docker network create --driver bridge devils_network`):

```
441be50f3792        bridge              bridge              local
0d73f7c6fe00        devils_network      bridge              local
8e189dda9fef        host                host                local
5ebca4a1e514        none                null                local
```

I run the container so:

```
docker run -it -d -v ~/dockervolume/deus:/srv/www --name deus --hostname deus --network=devils_network -p 80:8080 karl/node
```

And in the dockerfile expose port 8080:

```
EXPOSE  8080
```

I've attached a terminal session to the container and inspected the container to make sure the webserver is up and running:

```
root        17  0.0  0.1   4508   660 ?        S    22:46   0:00 sh -c NODE_PATH="$(pwd)" NODE_ENV=production node hello_world
root        19  0.0  4.3 882896 22004 ?        Sl   22:46   0:00 node hello_world
```

The webserver is utilizing port 8080 inside the docker container.

I'm running on a DigitalOcean droplet. If I start the server up directly on the host and not via a docker container it works.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to inverse the mapping -p 80:8080 to -p 8080:80 The 1st
   port is on the host and the second is the container's.
2. On your work/home network, make sure to redirect, in your router/fw, the        port 8080 to your docker host port 8080.

This should work:
Here is the same steps I performed with my nginx container:

```
docker network create --driver bridge devils_network
4320854ef67c5489848c1e1f14ffaf4d65183c5e3fac5f655c038bb15aa50df7  

docker run -it -v ~/dockervolume/deus:/usr/share/nginx/html --name deus --hostname deus --network=devils_network -p 8080:80 ajnouri/nginx
root@deus:/#
```

Copied an **index.php** file into **~/dockervolume/deus**:

And browsed my public IP from my phone:

[image]

Comment: Hi man! Thanks for the answer, I just realized I left out some important information regarding my question. The webserver is utilizing port 8080 inside the container. So I need to map hosts port 80 to the containers port 8080. Also running on DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 0):

Derp. I was using the following before in my Node.js application:

```
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 8080;
```

I changed it to:

```
const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 8080;
```

Now it's working. The reason I used `127.0.0.1` is because I'm so used to using a reverse proxy (HAProxy) to deal with this. However I want the docker container to directly connect to the internet and not go through a reverse proxy.