# Do I need to setup a Docker network to expose container to the Internet, and if so, how to do it?

Tags: docker, port-forwarding, windows-10

> **Summary**

I mounted a local Jenkins Build Server in a local Docker Container and exposed ports 8080 both from the host to the Jenkins container.

I want to test the integration of Jenkins with Azure DevOps so Jenkins is the build server for the project.

> **Docker**

I simply used the official jenkins/jenkins Docker image from Docker Hub and ran it like so:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name jenkins jenkins/jenkins
```

Container is reachable from `localhost:8080` and responds well.

> **Windows 10 Pro**

In Windows 10 Firewall I created two port rules:

1. Inbound, TCP, Local Port: All, Remote Port: All
2. Inbound, UDP, Local Port: All, Remote Port: All

> **Bell Fibe HomeHub 2000**

I created a port forwarding for my IP address which the modem did assosciate to the correct computer where the Docker container is running.

[image: Home Hub 2000 Port Forwarding]

> **Internet**

When I try to access my `[public ip address]:80` that I obtain by googling "what's my ip address", I hit this page.

[image: Site can't be reached]

> **Related SF Question**

[Webserver in Docker container is not reachable via the Internet](https://serverfault.com/questions/868837/webserver-in-docker-container-is-not-reachable-via-the-internet)

And I'm unsure as to how to proceed or even if it's necessary. I'm rather a software architect than a system admin, and I don't really understand the need of a Docker network if my ports forwarding is right.

Comment: Docker will do this itself. But your problem here is that "Docker for Windows" isn't, and isn't intended for production. Use Docker on a native Linux platform.

Comment: 1- You don't need to allow UDP in my opinion 
2 - I would also authorize outbound 8080 in Windows firewall

3 - can you telnet localhost:8080 ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access Jenkins using your public IP. If you want to access Jenkins publicly, you need a VPS with static public IP. And you should install Jenkins in that VPS.

The IP you're getting by google is your internet IP, not a server IP.